# Question about example ROS publisher code

Tags: python, ros

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
    self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
    timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
    self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
    self.i = 0

def timer_callback(self):
    msg = String()
    msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
    self.publisher_.publish(msg)
    self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
    self.i += 1
```

There was a example publisher code on the ROS site and I tried to study it, but I was confused at the `def __init__(self)`.

If you see the `self.timer_callback` in `def __init__(self)` part, the codes needs `self.i` but the `self.i` is bellow the `self.timer`, and it works without errors. I don't know how it works.

Could anyone help me understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible explanation is that the `self.create_timer` doesn't call the callback `self.timer_callback` instantly. It might wait for the `timer_period` (or some other time) before it calls the callback the first time, that's why the line `self.i = 0` executes before the `self.timer_callback` executes for the first time.

Comment: This is correct. ROS timers do not immediately execute the callback function.